# How to get my post title to work with an apostrophe ('s)?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, title, encoding, escaping

When saving a post with the title `Jule's Gormet`, it gets formatted as `Jule&#039;s Gormet`. If I save it again, it becomes `Jule&amp;#039;s Gormet`.

Following this pattern, it keeps escaping the ampersand and getting worse.

**More info**

- WordPress version: 3.3.2
- Theme: http://themetrust.com's Reveal (heavily modified)
- DB is UTF-8
- settings>reading has encoding set to UTF-8
- values are being stored in the database as `Jule&amp;amp;amp;#039;s` (etc..)

I've disabled all plugins and the problem persists.
I've gone through `functions.php` pretty well, and didn't find anything suspicious.
I followed the [troubleshooting guide](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-33-master-list?replies=5) in the brasofilo's comment - but to no effect.  Any ideas?

**Added this code per tommix**

```
function get_post_title($title) { 
    wp_mail('zlysobey@gmail.com','the title',$title); return $title; 
} add_filter ('title_save_pre','get_post_title');
```

**Which Yielded these results:**

- Jule\'s Gormet - 1st <del>attempt</del> save
- Jule's Gormet - 2nd <del>attempt</del> save
- Jule&#039;s Gormet - 3rd <del>attempt</del> save
- Jule&amp;#039;s Gormet - 4th <del>attempt</del> save

It actually sent 2 emails per save operation - maybe it means something? idk.

**On the Trail!**

so, I bit the bullet and started in on a fresh install - using all the edited theme code.  After liberally deleting stuff from the `functions.php`, I found the issue is somehow related to Bainternet's Tax-meta-class I'm using to add a field to one of my custom taxonomies.  Removing the following code fixes the issue. (though I'd like to figure out how to fix it while retaining my added taxonomy field.

```
// CUSTOM TAXONOMY FIELDS
require_once("Tax-meta-class/Tax-meta-class.php");
$config = array(
   'id' => 'focus_creative_services',
   'title' => 'creative services',
   'pages' => array('focus'),
   'context' => 'normal',
   'fields' => array(),
   'local_images' => false,
   'use_with_theme' => true
);
$creative_services_meta = new Tax_Meta_Class($config);
$creative_services_meta->addTextarea('textarea_field_id',array('name'=> 'Creative Services '));
$creative_services_meta->Finish();
```

I dropped a note to @Bainternet on his websites FAQ.  Hopefully he'll sort me out.

Comment: This doesn't happens to me in a 3.3.2 install. It may be a rogue plugin or theme function, and I'd suggest this [troubleshooting](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-33-master-list?replies=5).

Comment: Thanks for the checking your install (and the link).  I'll give it a read.  Maybe its a theme function. My only plugins are Contact-Form-7 and Mailchimp.

Comment: what does attempt means? it means saving/updating THE SAME post withouth changing title yes? Also did you try the fresh install with the same plugins and theme?

Comment: Yes - clicking update without changing anything.  I disabled all plugins on a relatively fresh install I had, and installed the (un-modified) theme.  The problem was not there.  It must be something I did, or somehow related to the wpalchemy class or Tax-meta-class I'm using.  I suppose I'll bite the bullet and test everything on a fresh install.

Comment: ADDITION: I used mine function i suggested to you to see what WP gets before saving title to DB and in all cases, i did 3 updates - i got mail with - Jule\'s Gormet . SO i think problem is in your server that is enabled magic_quotes_gpc

Comment: i edited my answer you may check it out :)

Comment: The code looks normal, i think the problem is in it's class (Tax-meta-class.php), not the function you've posted.

Comment: Yea, I think so too.  I left a msg on Bainternet (the author)'s message board.  Hopefully it will get resolved.  I took a quick look at the source with an eye to `stripslashes` but nothing jumped out at me.

Comment: I think problem is here `$attachment = stripslashes_deep( $attachment );` in class file, he strips slashes and i don't know why he is doing it? he's code is notvery good. But i just guessing i do not use his plugin, and also it's for attachments but maybe it strips all posts, so you loose your slash after first update, cause WP adss it before ' to prevent sql injection. try to comment out that line `$attachment = stripslashes_deep( $attachment );`

Comment: nope... its still doing it.  :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Disable magic_quotes_gpc in your server.
try adding in .HTACCESS file (if you on shared hosting):
`php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off`
If you'll get 500 server error after you added it - delete it and put this:
`ini_set ('magic_quotes_gpc', 0);` in theme's functions.php file. And with function bellow check is it on.

You can create php file with this content to test is it on (if on you'll see this nice string):

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    echo 'F@ck.. its on :D';
}
```

**2nd try:**
If the magic quotes was ok, than MAYBE you can try and search in your plugins, and theme's php files (with textcrawler) do some of them uses `stripslashes` function on title?

Comment: Sorry, I guesse it was sort of ambiguous, but in the admin it is *not* ok.  Also I don't think the entity decode will help, as it decodes `Jule&amp;&amp;&amp;#039;s` to `Jule&&&#039;s`. I'll check out all the stuff you mentioned though. Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know the encoding is UTF-8 - although other than settings>reading I'm not really sure how to check.  Database is verified UTF-8

Comment: So.. its saving in the database as `Jule&amp;amp;amp;#039;s Gormet`.  I'll update my question with this new info, and check out some stuff.  The htaccess file is pretty strandard.  Idk what else to check... Should I call the host maybe (1&1)?

Comment: Put this in your functions.php: `function get_post_title($title)      {`
     `wp_mail('your@email.com','the title',$title);`
     `return $title;` 
    `}`

`add_filter ('title_save_pre','get_post_title');` This will email you the title BEFORE it's stored to database, change email to your email, and after save you'll receive title -chack it does it come with good char? And write me.

Comment: Jule\'s Gormet - 1st attempt

Jule&#039;s Gormet - 2nd attempt

Jule\'s Gormet - 1st attempt

Jule&amp;#039;s Gormet - 3rd attempt

Jule&#039;s Gormet - 2nd attempt

Jule&amp;amp;#039;s Gormet - 4th attempt
Jule&amp;#039;s Gormet - 3rd attempt
Jule&amp;amp;amp;#039;s Gormet - 4th attempt

Comment: Well That came out ugly.  I'll add it to my question instead

Comment: yea, I'm thinking thats the next step...  I have a post on the theme authors page too, but no-ones biting so far.

Comment: you can simply change theme to default and check, if problem still exists than theme's developers are not fault :)

Comment: I loaded the same theme on another install and didn't have the same problem... refactoring my functions.php now; maybe ill find something...

Comment: plugins also may cause this not only your functions.

Comment: I tried disabling all (2) of them...

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help.  If I could give you more upvotes I would.  Unfortunately adding the line in htaccess causes an Internal Server Error

Comment: :D check my answer i also added code that you can put in php if you got 500 error. and it's not about votes it's about wanting to know what the hell causes this for you :D

Comment: I tried adding the php from the link into my main wordpress index.php file `ini_set ('magic_quotes_gpc', 0); ` but nothing seemed to change

Comment: this have to be in functions.php then. not header. my fault. if you use my checking code does it say F@ck its on? :D You also can reach your hosting support and ask do they enabled it or not, if yes-do they can disable it.

Comment: I'm marking your answer as correct, though I never actually got to the bottom of what precisely was going wrong.  I ended up removing Bainternet's code, and now everything works.